# TFS Object Model: Do WorkItems keep sessions open?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-sdk

We're currently investigating an issue, that, according to the Firewall provider, we have at times around 1500 parallel sessions open. I have the strong suspicion, that our TFS-Replication, a Service, which fetches Workitems via TFS Object Model from an external TFS and saves some data into a local SQL database, is causing the issue.

The access to the object model is looking like this:

```
        internal static async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<WorkItem>> QueryWorkItemsAsync(string wiqlQuery)
        {
            var tfsConfig = TFSConfiguration.Instances[Constants.TfsPrefix.External];
            var uri = new Uri(tfsConfig.WebbaseUri);
            var teamProject = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Infrastructure.Constants.APP_SETTINGS_TFS_PAT]));
            var workItemStore = teamProject.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

            var query = new Query(workItemStore, wiqlQuery, null, false);

            var result = await Task.Run(
                () =>
                {
                    var castedWorkItems = query.RunQuery().Cast<WorkItem>();
                    return castedWorkItems.ToList();
                });

            return result;
        }
```

Nothing too fancy: A WIQL can be passed into the method. Currently, I'm fetching blocks, so the WIQL would look like

```
            var wiql = "SELECT * FROM WorkItems";
            wiql += $" WHERE [System.Id] > {minWorkItemId}";
            wiql += $" AND [System.Id] <= {maxWorkItemId}";
            wiql += " ORDER BY [System.Id] DESC";
```

Im pretty much doing nothing with this WorkItems except mapping some of their fields, but not writing, saving or anything. I didn't get any hint on the objects I'm using regarding open Sessions and also the WorkItem-Objects itself are only very short living in the memory.

Am I missing something here, that could explain the open sessions within that service?

Comment: It looks like you code is querying the Event Viewer Database on the PC.  You can see the same results opening up the Event Viewer.  So you are just looking at log outputs which has nothing to to the the TFS connections.  If you are investing the TFS connections I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help look at the issues with the connection(s).

Comment: @Matthias Müller Have you resolved the issue by below answers? any update?

Comment: No, I passed it to out PL in order to plan and rework the feature, as soon as I get confirmation, I will mark the answer and probably write a small update with the findings.

Answer (score 2):

The client object model does a number of things:

- It keeps a connection pool for each user/projectcollection combination to speed up data transfers.
- Each work item revision you hit needs to be fetched.
- Each work item materialized from a query contains only the fields selected in the query, additional fields being accessed are fetched on demand.

The TFSTeamprojectCollection class implements IDisposable and must be cleaned up once in a while to ensure connections are closed. In internal cache is maintained, but it ensures that connections are closed.

Its probably a good idea to wrap this code in a try/catch block or provide the Team Project Collection through Dependency injection and manage the connection at a higher level (otherwise your additional fields will fail to be populated).

Comment: Thanks a lot, so the way to go would be to load the exact fields I need and then right away to dispose TFSTeamprojectCollection, there the connection is basically open once and closed immediately?

Comment: It should limit the number of connection pools open by your system. A few connections will probably be cached. haven't dug deeply into how exactly the caching mechanism works. It may be fastest, if this function is generic, to limit the query to just return `system.id` and from there just fetch the work item. Unless you know the list of fields you need, then specify the exact fields.

Comment: hm do you probably have a concrete idea how to limit the amount of connections on the tfs object model? I'm currently trying to fix this issue, but even if I just batch-execute 500 workitems and then dispose the teamprojectcollection, I open a ton of sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the very details behind the workitem class but I observed that when u e.g. specify in the select of the wiql only a few fields u can still access others ... And that is comparable slow. If I select all fields I later access through indexer it is much faster.
From that observation I would say: yes, a communication is kept open.